# Search inside wordpress backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a new menu item inside the wordpress admin bar called "Manage users". 
Here I have a search bar where I'm able to search for registered people using "name" & "last_name", but I don't want just simple results.
What I want is, when I do a search, the result/s come inside a link, and when one result is clicked, the page of that user should be opened. OK. The big problem is, I don't know how to create the page where each user can be managed and how to link it with the results.
Hope you understand me.

I know how to get info from dB & edit dB info but not much more...

Can anybody help my with this? Thank you!

Comment: you have the id of user right?
i mean u list them and when you do u should know how to have their ID

Comment: Yes, I have the ID

Answer (score 0):

with  `<?php get_edit_user_link($user_id) ?>` Get the link to the users edit profile page in the WordPress admin.
and then simply say:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_edit_user_link($user_id); ?>">name</a>
```

and u already have the username to replace with name i think

you can also read documention [Function Reference/get edit user link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_edit_user_link)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I use custom users registration, so this don't help me :/

Comment: so how you manage to see your users and where to create theme, send user ID as get method maybe + check the user rule then in your new page load user data from DB in fields, am i right? you need php helps actually explain me a bit more so i can help :)